# Where is the public internet endpoint of a cloud foundary app?

Tags: ibm-cloud

I created a sample app in cloud foundary. The app runs fine after deployment. I also specified random-route in the manifest file. The app was assigned a domain name in the mybulemix.net domain. But the full domain name always returns a 169.x.x.x IP. This is a private IP address. How can I access my app from the internet? Where is the public IP of my app and what's the domain name for it?

Comment: You *must* access it using the fully qualified host name, not the IP address. Your application does not get a unique IP address--that would never scale in the cloud.

Comment: Yes, I understand that I need to use a full qualified domain name. What I mean is the FQDN always resolves to a 169.x.x.x IP, which is a private IP. So how am I supposed to access my service with it through the internet?

Comment: I'm confused. Does it not respond when you access it by hostname?

Answer (score 0):

OK, it seems that the 169 IP still can be routed on the internet and can be used the access the service. It's just the service itself doesn't work.